# What's the deal with GAS in Ethereum?

Tags: gas, gas-price

What benefits exactly we get from using gas in the network and why do we need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gas is used as an ETH independent unit of accounting.

It let's you define how much a certain operation in the EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) should cost in relation to each other. In this sense it is a cost structure.

The benefit is to decouple the incentive structure for cheap opcodes from a certain price. If the value of ETH increases, miners can choose to lower their demand for fees in ether smoothly. So with this, a mining fee market can always adapt to ETH valuation.

Comment: So who determines the gas price?

Comment: The user that sends a transaction to a contract can pick any gas price, but the miners don't have to accepted it. It is a market.

Comment: You mean the miners pay the price and the sender benefits from it? Or it is exactly the other way? excuse me if this is a dumb Q

Comment: No the sender proposes a `gasPrice` he has to pay. The miner can accept it or refuse it because it is too low. There is a default gas price of 10 Szabo currently. 1 ETH is 1 million Szabo.

Comment: Ok, so at the end it's the miner who benefits from the `gasPrice` right?

Comment: Absolutely, the miner needs an incentive to run contract for the sender. The sender crafts a transaction where he sets the gasPrice and the maximal amount of Gas he is willing to spend, the `gasLimit`. The miner then runs the contract until the function returns or the gasLimit is reached. All spend Gas is multiplied with the gas price and detracted from sender's account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40691/discussion-between-roland-kofler-and-vardumper).

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum is essentially a single Quasi Turing-complete computer, capable of computation just like any other computer, except for every instruction executed, there must be something expendable known as gas. Gas is essentially a limited resource required to run computation to ensure that every contract will halt/terminate and did not cause Denial of Service.

tl;dr Ethereum Developers' solution for halting problem.

Comment: This couldn't be done using Ether? Why bother to introduce another factor?

Comment: Gas is priced in ether.